# How do I set customized placeholder in 'booster.widgets.TbActiveForm'?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I use like this..

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $User,'email_address',
       array(
         'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
           'class'=> 'col-sm-5',

         ),

        )   
        );
    ?>
</div>
```

But there is default placeholder 'Email Address'. How I want to set there my own placeholder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add html options as below:

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $User,'email_address',
    array(
        'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
            'class'=> 'col-sm-5',

        ),
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'my placeholder'
            )
        )

    )
);
?>
```

for more detail have a look at [Booster active form](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms/view/activeform.html)